# Método quivalente ao array_diff() no JAVA

Tags: php, java, array

No PHP existe o método `array_diff()` que verifica valores de dois *arrays* e retorna os itens referente a diferença entre eles. Por exemplo:

```
$arrExclusion = array('as', 'coisas', 'acontece', 'no', 'tempo', 'certo');

$arr = array('tudo', 'as', 'coisas' 'acontece', 'me', 'é', 'no', 'lícito',
'mas', 'seu', 'nem', 'tudo', 'tempo', 'me', 'convém', 'certo' );

$new_array = array_diff($arr, $arrExclusion);
```

Os valores do *array* `$new_array` serão:

> 'tudo', 'me', 'é', 'lícito', 'mas', 'nem', 'tudo', 'me', 'convém'

Existe alguma método equivalente ao `array_diff()` no JAVA? Se sim, qual? Se não, como poderia realizar esse procedimento?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1235033/java-comparing-two-string-arrays-and-removing-elements-that-exist-in-both-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a biblioteca [Commons Collections](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/) o método **removeAll** da classe [CollectionUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.2/index.html) removendo os elementos de um array de outro, ficando da seguinte maneira:

```
List<String> arrExclusion = Arrays.asList("as", "coisas", "acontece", "no", "tempo", "certo");

List<String> arr = Arrays.asList("tudo", "as", "coisas", "acontece", "me", "é", "no", "lícito","mas", "seu", "nem", "tudo", "tempo", "me", "convém", "certo");

Collection<String> new_array = CollectionUtils.removeAll(arr, arrExclusion);
```

Gerando o seguinte resultado:

> [tudo, me, é, lícito, mas, seu, nem, tudo, me, convém]

Answer (score 0):

Arrays não tem um método que realize o *diff* entre arrays.

Para fazer isso podemos fazer o seguinte:

```
String[] s1 = {"ram", "raju", "seetha"};
String[] s2 = {"ram"};
List<String> s1List = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(s1));
for (String s : s2) {
  if (s1List.contains(s)) {
    s1List.remove(s);
  }
  else {
    s1List.add(s);
  }
}
```

[demonstração](http://ideone.com/cdH0LE)

descrito na pergunta equivalente em inglês: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220752/find-string-array-difference-in-java